# bootstrap navbar - collapse not working after trying out brand in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at this bootply:  http://www.bootply.com/mQh8DyRfWY#

The collapse works fine on the bootply, but in my project I am not able to toggle it.  Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ramsiteApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

          </div>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Ram M's Tea Man</a>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/services">Services</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.browsehappy {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
}

/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */
.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Custom page header */
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}

/* Custom page footer */
.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}

/* Supporting marketing content */
.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}

/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }

  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

If I remove the css for .navbar-brand, then it works fine but it doesn't look correct.

Please advise how to proceed.  Thank you

Comment: *The collapse works fine on the bootply, but in my project I am not able to toggle it.* There may be other problems. A link to your webpage or problematic demo would be better.

Comment: @Ram as of now there's a catch while using *Bootstrap* `javascript` components along with *Angular*, so may be i.e. the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `navbar-brand` is covering your toggle button since it's set to 100% width. See working example.

```css
.browsehappy {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */

.header,
.marketing,
.footer {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Custom page header */

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered,
.navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */

.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}
/* Custom page footer */

.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
/* Main marketing message and sign up button */

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}
/* Supporting marketing content */

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}
/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="ramsiteApp">
  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
        </div> <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#/">Ram M's Tea Man</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/services">Services</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the Yeoman team</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```